# fviz_clust choose name of axis in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

I'm new to R and I have a question regarding the package factoextra and the function fviz_nbclust().

I want to rename myself the axis X and Y but i can't find how to do it. I found how to add the title but not the axis.

```
fviz_nbclust(new_data, kmeans, method = "wss") +
geom_vline(xintercept = 4 , linetype = 2)+
labs(title= "K-means")
```

Does anyone know how to rename the axis ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal working example I can't be sure but something like

```
fviz_nbclust(new_data, kmeans, method = "wss") +
geom_vline(xintercept = 4 , linetype = 2)+
labs(title= "K-means") + 
xlab("New x label") +
ylab("New y label")
```

See ggplot docs for more info http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/labs.html

If you're new to stackoverflow please remember to provide a minimal working when asking a question and select and up-vote a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And for the next time i will remember :)